# Can anyone please explain this output with a slight modification in the usual getchar_unlocked function()?

Tags: c++, ascii, output, getchar

I wanted to change the general getchar_unlocked program to print the position of space when the second number is entered.So i introduced 2 more variables r and a, such that r gets incremented every time a non space character is input and a gets r's value when a space character is input.  However, by the change i made only the first no. is getting stored in s and a garbage value is getting stored in a. Why so?

```
   #include <cstdio>
   #define getcx getchar_unlocked
   using namespace std;
   inline void scan( int &n, int &a) //extra parameter a added
  {
    n=0; int r=0;

    char ch;
    ch=getcx();
    while (ch<'0' || ch>'9') //Inclusion of a !=' ' condition 
   {
       if (ch==' ') 
        a=r;
       else
        r++;
      ch=getcx();
   }
   while (ch>='0' &&  ch<='9')
    {
     r++;

     n=10*n + ch -'0';
     ch=getcx();
     }
   }

 int main()
 {

   int t,s,a;
   scan(t,a);
   printf("%d\n",t);

   scan(s,a);
    printf("%d",s); 
   printf("%d",a);
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: May be using your preferred  debugging tool, and stepping through your code line by line could shed some light on what's actually wrong. But it's ***you***, not us to do this, and investigate!

Comment: what does this have to do with `getchar_unlocked`?  `getchar` will behave identically (and you should use it in preference, unless you know what you are doing and have called `flockfile` previously)

Comment: My debugger isnt working properly. I had even posted a question regarding it a few days back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197452/code-blocks-10-05-debugger-in-ubuntu-unable-to-use-it

Comment: @Chris Dodd- I assumed that getchar_unlocked was an a time saving extension of getchar. I have come across the term flockfile for the first time

Comment: @weston, Final Contest and Rakibul Hasan - How is the desired behaviour of my code not explained when the statement above the code begins in that tune? Also, how could i have possibly reduced my code further? All that my code contains is an int main() to describe the input procedure and another function scan() which describes the problem i am facing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scan` function skips non-digits, then reads 1 or more digits as an integer into `n`, and finally skips a single non-digit character.   In the first loop to skip non-digits, it counts the number of non-spaces read and stores that number into `a` whenever it sees a space.  If it never sees a space, `a` will remain unmodified.

So if you give your program an input like `10 20` (with just a single space), that space will be skipped by the first call to scan (the non-digit after the number), and `a` will never be initialized.

If you want your `scan` routine to *not* skip the character after the number it reads, you need to call `ungetc` to put it back after reading it and discovering that it is not a digit.

Comment: wr2 what you've mentioned in your second para, when the loop is run to skip a charachter ,Shouldn't the same loop be initializing a too

Comment: No, because it is skipped by the second loop in `scan` (the one reading digits) which does not set a.

Comment: okay, so when it encounters a space, it comes out of the loop . One more query, why doesn't the control go out of the function then ? Why does the control get transfered to the first line of the function.?

Comment: Why do you think control goes to the first line of the function?  After reading the space, `scan` returns to main, which call `printf` and then `scan` again -- so it gets back to the first line that way, but it returns first.

Comment: Ok.. thanks al lot.. this really cleared the cloud

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value of `r` to pointer `a` with `a=r;`, should be `*a=r;` and you have similar problems with `n=10*n + ch -'0';` should be `*n=10*(*n) + ch -'0';`. Never forget your function arguments `( int &n, int &a)` make `n` and `a` pointers and will need to be dereferenced to assign values. In fact, in the original thread, I took the arguments to be pseudo-code (int &n, int &a), int actual implementation, I would do `(int *n, int *a)` and adjust the code accordingly.

Here is how I updated the original, this illustrates the pass by reference implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define getcx getchar_unlocked

/* input parser reads - sign, and any digits that follow */
inline void inp ( int *num )
{
    int n = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    char ch = getcx();

    /* get the sign */
    while ( ch < '0' || ch > '9' )
        { if (ch == '-') sign = -1; ch = getcx();}

    /* add each char read. n is accumulator, (n << 3) + (n << 1) is just n * 10 */
    while (  ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' )
        n = (n << 3) + (n << 1) + ch - '0', ch = getcx(); /* = n*10 + ch - 48 */

    n = n * sign;

    *num = n;
}

int main (void) {

    int number = 0;
    printf ("enter something containing nummbers\n");

    inp (&number);

    printf ("number: %d\n", number);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Aren't a and n being passed as reference variables ?

Comment: You are correct, updated.

Comment: This is the usual procedure which returns negative nos. also. My code differed from it because i wanted to print the position of the first space entered from the console. Hence i introduced a variable r which was incremented for each digit entered . When the user would enter a space, r's value should have been transfered to a. But sadly, it didnt execute that way which confused me. I removed the negative no. (sign variable step ) because i didnt need it.